# JSon Exception In IDE

Tags: java, json, ide

I have a call to the following function using

```
String subjects = callWebService(query);
DisplaySubjects(subjects);
```

But I get a JsonException in the IDE so I cant even compile it. subjects would be a valid Json String returned from the Ws.(tested)

```
public void displaySubjects(String subjects) throws JSONException 
{
    try 
    {
        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(subjects);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);


        setListAdapter(adapter);

    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And I dont know why?

EDIT:
In When I go to compile I get this error on the Caller Line:
error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. 
But I am doing that correct?

Comment: What is the exception that you get? 
And this is a little off-topic, but Java naming convention specifies that your method name starts with in lowercase  :)

Comment: Make sure that retrieving the values by index i is valid.

Comment: All it says is Unhandled Exception org.json.JsonException when I mouse over the squiggly.  I cant Compile, Debug ...Nothing. So its hard to find out why this is happening.I was thinking I was calling the function incorrectly.DisplaySubjects(subjects) has the squiggly.

Comment: What IDE? Is this a compiler error message, or is it an IDE error?

Comment: I got rid of the error by deleting "throws JSONException" . I dont know what that will do in the long run though.

Answer (score 0):

displaySubjects() method is throwing a JSONException which (likely suspect) is a subclass of a checked exception, which means callers to this method would need catch this exception, i.e. enclose in a try{}catch or throw out this exception propagated from displaySubjects().

Simply, for example if you were calling this from another method:

```
public void displayControl(String json){
  try{
    displaySubjects(json);
  }catch(JSONException){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Or you could throw out that exception.

```
public void displayControl(String json) throws JSONException{
  displaySubjects(json);
}
```

Further to this, I noticed that the displaySubjects() method catches any occurrence of JSONException and rethrows as a runtime exception. The effect of this is that, actually, you would not need to explicitly throw out the JSONException from displaySubjects(). So unless it is unintentional that you are catching the JSONException from within and rethrowing as a runtime exception, you may take away that throws JSONException clause from displaySubjects().

Runtime exceptions do not need to be caught.